# WPF ShowDialog on thread: stop dispatcher needed?

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

I got a console Application that opens a modal WPF Window on a separate thread similar to this example:

http://reedcopsey.com/2011/11/28/launching-a-wpf-window-in-a-separate-thread-part-1/

```
// Create a thread
Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart( () =>
{
    // Create and show the Window
    Window1 tempWindow = new Window1();
    tempWindow.Show();
    // Start the Dispatcher Processing
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
}));
```

But I'm using ShowDialog instead of Show.

What I see is, that I don't need to start a dispatcher thread in that case. ShowDialog seems to do that under the hood.

But what about shutdown of the dispatcher thread? Do I need to do that explicitly in that case by calling *InvokeShutdown*?
Or does the close method on the window handle that already?

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to do it that way, since I have to deal with a legacy application. That application needs to show a modal dialog in some cases. So right now there is no other way.

Comment: If you must place dialogs into a legacy application, I would think using [p-invoke](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364681/message-box-in-front-of-all-windows-in-console-application) to [MessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) would have the smallest footprint.  You don't want to WPF-ify your legacy application too much.

Comment: That was my first approach. Not my decision, but there is a need to have a different style which requieres WPF.

Answer (score 0):

The concern being describe with respect to calling `Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown()` is that, having started the thread, the thread will not exit naturally until the `Dispatcher.Run()` method returns, and it won't know to do that until you call `InvokeShutdown()`. Note that this is in contrast to the Winforms API, in which you can pass a `Form` instance reference to the `Application.Run()` method, and the method there will return when that `Form` instance has been closed.

In the case of calling `ShowDialog()`, no new thread is created: the dialog window is handled in the current thread. As such, there is obviously no risk of blocking the thread used for the window; it's the current thread, and you know it's not blocked after the window is closed, because the `ShowDialog()` method returns control to your own code.

So, no. You not need to worry about calling `InvokeShutdown()` in the case where you are using `ShowDialog()`.